# Failed to start the apache HTTP server

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server

After pushing my Laravel project on my development server, it seems that I can not run apache 2 anymore.

After running the command line :

> sudo systemctl status apache2

I get the following error :

> ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-03 02:17:48 UTC;
>   1min 17s ago   Process: 1631 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

After searching a bit on Google it appears that apache can not start because multiple processes are using port 80..

However, after running the command line :

> sudo lsof -i tcp:80

I get the list of the following processes :

> COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME google_ne 716
>   root    7u  IPv4  18497      0t0  TCP
>   instance-development-webapp-eatology.c.webapp-eatology.internal:34086->metadata.google.internal:http
>   (ESTABLISHED) google_ac 717 root    5u  IPv4  18475      0t0  TCP
>   instance-development-webapp-eatology.c.webapp-eatology.internal:34082->metadata.google.internal:http
>   (ESTABLISHED) google_cl 719 root    5u  IPv4  18478      0t0  TCP
>   instance-development-webapp-eatology.c.webapp-eatology.internal:34084->metadata.google.internal:http
>   (ESTABLISHED) google_cl 719 root    6u  IPv4  18402      0t0  TCP
>   instance-development-webapp-eatology.c.webapp-eatology.internal:34080->metadata.google.internal:http
>   (CLOSE_WAIT)

Problem is, I do not understand how to kill each one of these processes, I've tried many command lines without any success..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: To kill a process, look at the number under the PID column header, which in your case, I see 716, 717, 719 for the individual processes. Your command to terminate them will be `sudo kill PID` where *PID* has to be replaced by the appropriate number. However, the Google cloud instances might just restart again. So, the better option would be to start Apache on a different port number instead of the default 80.

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 80
```

Look at the line where you have :

```
Proto : tcp
Local address : *.*.*.*:80
```

Get the Pid or the Process Name column value :

```
<pid_or_process_name>:80
```

Kill the process that holds the ports 80 using its pid or process name :

```
pkill -9 <process_name>
```

Or

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Finally this still a workaround, you have to find out  the process that is responsible of exposing the port 80 and disable it or just change its configuration file to point on a different port rather than tcp/80 because you will be on the same issue after a reboot.